# LaTeX: Put two images next to the text

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I have two images and I want put them next to the text, but I don't know how to do this. The images have to be one under the other.

```
\section{Procedimento}
\begin{wrapfigure}{H}{5cm}
\caption{Il metro teso grazie alla sedia}\label{wrap-fig:2}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{metrofisso2.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\begin{wrapfigure}{H}{5cm}
\caption{Il metro teso grazie alla sedia}\label{wrap-fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{metrofisso1.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure} 

Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per 
poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia 
affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare 
il metro.
In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle.......
```

I tried this but the positions aren't right. How can I do this?

Comment: wrapfigure doesn't have an H option. you can put both images into the same wrapfigure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, but in this way there is a white space which covers a part of the text

Comment: No, there should not be but you have not provided any usable example so hard to guess what is wrong

Answer (score 4):

You can put both images in the same wrapfig

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Procedimento}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\caption{Il metro teso grazie alla sedia}\label{wrap-fig:2}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}

\bigskip

\caption{Il metro teso grazie alla sedia}\label{wrap-fig:1}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\end{wrapfigure} 
Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per 
poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia 
affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare 
il metro.
In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle.......

Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per 
poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia 
affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare 
il metro.
In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle.......

Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per 
poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia 
affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare 
il metro.
In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle.......

Inizialmente scegliere le misure delle altezze e un luogo opportuno per 
poterle marcare, come ad esempio un muro. Dopodiché posizione la prima sedia 
affianco al muro che avrà 2 funzioni: raggiungere elevate altezze, fissare 
il metro.
In questo modo, esso sarà completamente teso, ottenendo così delle.......
\end{document}
```

(note that this is a complete document that you can run to get the posted output, if things are still not working for you, fix the example in your question so that it demonstrates the problem)

Comment: I did in this way: `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \vspace{-40pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{metrofisso1.jpg}
    \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{metrofisso3.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \caption{\color{blue} Il metro teso e fissato con la sedia}
  \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}`, so there isn't the white space which covers the text

Comment: @Curio you have mentioned white space covering text several times but given no hint on why there is any white space over the text. Also you should use `\centering` rather than `center` so you don''t need so much negative space.